# What is "Memory Page out Rate"

Tags: linux

Could somebody please tell me what is "Memory Page Out Rate".
I have seen this in "HP Open View" server monitoring tool and tried googling it.
Would appreciate if some expert can clarify.

If page out rate is too high as 200+ per second, can it crash the server?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This link may help:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v15r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.itm.doc/main_unix65.htm

"**Page Out Rate** (KB per Second) *The number of kilobytes that the virtual memory manager pages out per second averaged over the previous 30-second interval. Note: the value -1 indicates Not Available, -2 indicates Not Collected, 2147483648 indicates Value_Exceeds_Minimum, and -2147483647 indicates Value_Exceeds_Maximum.*"

A page-out rate of 200kb/s could be fine on some systems and service affecting on others. It all depends on how fast your disks/san can keep up.

To be honest you'd be better off asking this question in one of these more suitable sites, SO is for programming related questions, not sysadmin queries:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321618/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is the **GBL_MEM_PAGEOUT** variable of HP OVPM.

To my understanding it means that some process allocated memory and never de-allocated it, and that process is not currently active.

So basically it should be as low as possible.

However, according to the HP OVPM Metrics document, the definition is this:

> **GBL_MEM_PAGEOUT**
>   PLATFORMS: HP-UX AIX NCR Sinix DEC SunOS Win3X/95
>
> **HP-UX AIX NCR Sinix DEC** 
>   The total number of page outs to the disk
>   during the interval. This includes pages paged out to paging space and
>   to the file system.
>
> **HP-UX** 
>   This metric is available on HP-UX 11.0 and beyond.
>
> **AIX**
>   This is the same as the “page outs” value from the “vmstat -s”
>   command. Remember that “vmstat -s” reports cumulative counts.
>
> This metric cannot be compared to the “po” value from the “vmstat”
>   command. The “po” value only reports the number of pages paged out to
>   paging space.
>
> To determine the count (that is, GBL_MEM_PAGEOUT) for the current
>   interval, subtract the previous value from the current value. To
>   determine the rate (that is, GBL_MEM_PAGEOUT_RATE) for the current
>   interval, subtract the previous value from the current value and then
>   divide by the length of the interval. Keep in mind that whenever any
>   comparisons are made with other tools, both tools must be interval
>   synchronized with each other in order to be valid.
>
> **HP-UX SunOS**
>   The total number of page outs to the disk during the
>   interval. This includes pages paged out to paging space and to the
>   file system.
>
> **Win3x/95** 
>   The total number of page outs to the disk during the interval
>   (Windows 95 only).